# website Auto fetch messages to php chat application not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

in a PHP chat application, using `status='0'` for `unread message` and `status='1'` for `read messages` for notification. I need `auto-fetch messages` if the user gets a new message in the `chat.php` script. I am using ajax for fetching auto messages, but not working.

Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
// check once in five seconds 
setInterval(function() { 
$.get('chat.php', {
do: 'new_messages'
}, function(response) 
{ 
if(response == 1) {
 window.location.reload(); 
}
 }); 
}, 5000);
 });
```

php script:

```
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
 require('conn.php'); 
$sql = "SELECT status from chat where tothe='$email' order by id desc"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
 if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 return $there_are_new_messages; 
}
 if($there_are_new_messages) {
 echo 1; exit;
 } 
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Ajax script:
$(document).ready(function() {
  // check once in five seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get('chat.php', {do: 'new_messages'}, function(response) {
      if(response == 1) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }, 5000); 
});

Comment: php script:
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
  require('conn.php');
  $sql = "SELECT `status` from `chat` where tothe='$email' order by id desc";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
         if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
return $there_are_new_messages;
}
  if($there_are_new_messages) {
     echo 1; 
     exit;
  }
}

Comment: Always put the script in question body not in comment.

Comment: Did you define `$there_are_new_messages` in your code?

Comment: yes..if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
  require('conn.php');
  $sql = "SELECT `status` from `chat` where tothe='$email' order by id desc";
         $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
         if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
return $there_are_new_messages;
}
  if($there_are_new_messages) {
     echo 1; 
     exit;
  }
}

Comment: @fazalza ArtisticPhoenix explained the syntax of your code well.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry your code formatting is atrocious, but I cleaned it up.  Once doing that it's more readable and things began to make sense.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    // check once in five seconds 
    setInterval(function() { 
        $.get('chat.php', {do: 'new_messages'}, function(response){ 
            if(response == 1) {
                window.location.reload(); 
            }
        }); 
    }, 5000);
}); 

if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
    require('conn.php'); 
    $sql = "SELECT status from chat where tothe='$email' order by id desc"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        return $there_are_new_messages; 
    }
    if($there_are_new_messages) {
        echo 1; 
        exit;
    } 
}
```

Based on the code you have posted.

This variable is no where to be seen `$there_are_new_messages`.  This unknown variable is pretty key to the code you have.  Without it:

```
- you return nothing
- the second (fall back) if condition fails.
```

Let's assume it's `1`.

If the first if condition succeeded, you found results. You would return this variable or as we are guessing a `1`. Now in the fall back if, it's the conditional, 1 is true so that's fine, then we echo a hard coded 1.  So we return a 1 for one, if that fails we echo a 1 for the fall back.  Basically the same value is "returned" (more on this latter)

Now let's assume it's `0`.

If the first if condition succeeded, you found results. You would return this variable or as we are guessing a `0`. Now in the fall back if, it's the conditional, 0 is not true so the if condition cannot pass and nothing is echoed. So again in both cases we return a falsy value, or what I mean is a similar value for both return/outputs.

These are just guesses as that variable, and more importantly the value it contains is not included in the question.

To me logically this return value seems wrong.  The question, is there new messages Yes (return ?) No (return 1).  To me 1 means true, and 0 means false.  Perhaps you are asking how many new messages? then it would make sense logically, but that doesn't seem to be the case as no counted value is returned.  This is just an Opinion though, so take it at face value.

Further:

```
 return $there_are_new_messages;
```

We cannot return things to the client.  We have to output them. Or in other words `echo` so this return has no effect.

```
 $sql = "SELECT status from chat where tothe='$email' order by id desc";
```

Likewise `$email` is undefined, so this SQL is doomed to failure.  Not to mention you are just sticking it in the query with no regard for security. So this opens the potential for SQLInjection attacks against your database. Even if you think this value is secure, I would still use prepared statements. You lose nothing by using them, and if you change the code later you don't have to worry if it's now insecure.  You could change where `$email` is set from, and it may have an impact on security, and you may not remember this query was not sanitized properly etc...

Lastly:

I would try to fix it but without knowing what `$there_are_new_messages` is supposed to be and given what I like to call `variable confusion` which is to say I don't know what these variables represent because they are used in confusing ways.  There not much I can do but explain what I see that is wrong.

Sure I could piece together some solution, that may or may not be what you want, but I think it's better to point out were things are falling apart then to try to make assumptions.  For example, `$email` is undefined.  Where does it come from, how do you get it.  Is it an input on the page, is it pulled from a user record in the DB, is it part of the $_SESSION data. I have no way to know, there for I cannot give a reasonable answer.

PS. Don't take any of this the wrong way. Often, I am told, I can come off as condescending or like I am talking down. That is not the intent, I'm just being blunt and to the point.  Everyone makes mistakes coding and everyone has to learn, usually by trial and error.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you don't need use return.

```
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
    require('conn.php'); 
    $sql = "SELECT status from chat where tothe='$email' order by id desc"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row["status"];
    } else {
        echo 1;
    }
    exit;
}
```

I don't know why you use `$there_are_new_messages` without declaration, anyway if you wanna use `$there_are_new_messages` you can use like this.

```
if(isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] == 'new_messages') {
    require('conn.php'); 
    $sql = "SELECT status from chat where tothe='$email' order by id desc"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    $there_are_new_messages = false;
    if($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        $there_are_new_messages = $row["status"];
    } 

    if($there_are_new_messages){
        echo 0;
    } else {
        echo 1;
    }

    exit;
}
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  // check once in five seconds
  setInterval(function() {
    $.get('chat.php', {do: 'new_messages'}, function(response) {
      if(response == 1) {
        window.location.reload();
      }
    });
  }, 5000); 
});

Comment: @fazalza How about use developer console (or developer tool) in chrome? In network tab, you can check about ajax connection.

Comment: And sorry, i miss ". `$row["status"];`

Comment: not still reloading the page.. new message is available with status=0 but not reloading the page

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. i miss understand 0 is read. try code again.
And did you check your developer console?

Comment: @fazalza And ArtisticPhoenix's answer is really good to you. I hope you read it in time. His answer is better than mine.